# Why in my code .find() runs If condition when it finds no docs in database in CRUD

Tags: mongodb

According to me , i have condition in my crud that when i login and give correct password then database give me docs, but if i give wrong password then it goes to else condition and console that -Not in database...,

But the output is diffrent when i type wrong password it not goes on else condition it goes on if condition and gives me docs in empty array (like this..[ ])

i want when find docs then it goes if condition and if not find docs it goes on else condition

```
//CRUD   
-----------------------------------------------------------
const userModel = require("../models/schema");

const userOperation = {
add(object,response){
    userModel.create (object,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log("err in adding database.......");
        }
        else{
            console.log("user added............");
        }
    })
},

search(object,response){
    userModel.find(object,(err,docs)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log("nothing in database................");
            response.status(500).json({status:'E',message:'Error in DB During Find Operation'});
        }
        else{
        if(docs){
            console.log(docs);
            response.json(docs);
            console.log("user find in databse.......")
        }
        else{
            console.log("user not find in database...............")

        }
    }
    })

}
}
 module.exports= userOperation;



//SCHEMA
-----------------------------------------------------------------
const connection = require("../models/connection");
const schema = connection.Schema;
const userModel = new schema({
'name':{type:String,require:true, },
'email':{ type:String,require:true,},
'phone':{ type:Number,require:true,}
})

const userSchema = connection.model('damn',userModel);
module.exports =  userSchema;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `userModel.findOne()` instead, this way if the query doesn't find any user the doc will return `null` otherwise, you can still use `userMode.find()` but instead of just using `if(doc)` use `if(doc.length>0)`